# Error while upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04, GCC-6-base

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, gcc6

I'm trying to upgrade my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04, while doing

```
sudo apt update
```

&

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

and keep getting

> The following packages have been kept back: GCC-6-base

I tried to install, upgrade and remove this package but keep getting

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libgail-common:
> Depends: libgail18 (= 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2) but it is not going to
> be installed  libgcc1: Depends: GCC-6-base (= 6.0.1-0ubuntu1) but
> 6.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04.york0 is to be installed  libwxgtk3.0-0v5: Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not going to be installed or
> libgl1
> Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed E: Error, pkgProblemResolver:: Resolve generated breaks,
> this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: Please ask on http://askubunutu.com instead; StackOverflow is only for questions about programming issues.  Note that the accepted way to upgrade Ubuntu versions is not just with `apt upgrade` but `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: **sudo do-release-upgrade**
"Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."